# Best way to interact with a client/server application through internet?

Tags: java, client-server, vnc

I have a 3rd party client/server application, not developed by me, who needs to be accessed through Internet. I need to provide an interaction layer to do so, through a website, no matter the technique/programming language. I thought on maybe using VNC or a similar remote control software, but I'm open to any suitable solution to that.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VNC, citrix or Windows Remote Desktop might be options, if you actuall want to see the GUI.

If you prefere to make the features but available but behind a GUI of your own design, I'd try a toolkit intended for gui testing. Like this one for example: http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/windowtester-pro-gui-tester

Install the application on a machine and build a web app on the same machine

A third option would be to decompile the app in order to change it. Of course this might be illegal.

Note: for many applications it would be illegal to make them available through the internet, no matter what technique you are using.